# Getting the user who created a 365 group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is it possible to extract from Microsoft Graph to fetch what user has created a specific 365 group? I need to get which user created specific team site.

Best R, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non admins users you can use this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group object id}/createdOnBehalfOf`

For every user you can use the [List directoryAudits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response) operation with the following query and extract initiatedBy/user/id from each returned record.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=category eq 'GroupManagement' and activityDisplayName eq 'Add group'`